# Hooking in eclipse Folder refactoring

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

In my plugin I have a requirement for keeping track of certain folders if they are renamed. For that I used the `org.eclipse.ltk.core.refactoring.renameParticipants` extension point and created class subclassing `RenameParticipant`class. inside that I am able to get the old and new path for the renamed Folder inside `checkCondition` method some thing like this -

```java
public RefactoringStatus checkConditions(IProgressMonitor pm, CheckConditionsContext context)
        throws OperationCanceledException {
    ResourceChangeChecker checker = (ResourceChangeChecker) context.getChecker(ResourceChangeChecker.class);
    IResourceChangeDescriptionFactory deltaFactory = checker.getDeltaFactory();
    IResourceDelta resourceDelta = deltaFactory.getDelta();
    IResourceDelta[] changedResources =  resourceDelta.getAffectedChildren();
    for(IResourceDelta resource : changedResources) {
        if(resource.getResource().getType() == IResource.PROJECT){
            IResourceDelta[] changedFolders = resource.getAffectedChildren(IResource.FOLDER);
            for(IResourceDelta folderResource : changedFolders) {
                System.out.println("Folder changed - "+folderResource.getResource().getName());
                System.out.println("Folder changed old path- "+folderResource.getResource().getFullPath());
                IPath path = folderResource.getMovedToPath();
                String newFileName = path.toFile().getName();
                System.out.println("Moved To - " + folderResource.getMovedToPath());
                System.out.println("New Resource Name - " + newFileName);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

My question are-

1. I am just returning null at end of the method. is it OK ? or should I return a new `RefactoringStatus` status object ?  or am I doing it all wrong ?
2. There is another method created `createChange` while subclassing `RenameParticipant`. What's the purpose of this method/what should I write in this method ?

Answer (score 0):

You should return a `RefactoringStatus` from `checkConditions`. Just use

```java
return new RefactoringStatus();
```

if everything is OK.

The rename may actually be cancelled by a rename participant so it is not safe to assume the change will happen in the `checkConditions` method. It is intended that this method is only used to check that the rename is safe to do as far as your participant is concerned.

You use `createChange` if you need to actually do some operation when the rename is done. The `Change` object returned is called as part of the rename process. You should use a `Change` object to do your tracking so that you are sure the rename has actually occurred.

Comment: I don't need to do any additional checks before renaming so just returning a new `RefactoringStatus`should do ? Also how can I get hold of the current `Change` object ?

Comment: If you have no checks that just returning the status is OK. There is no 'current' Change object - you must create a class extending `Change` which does what you want and return a new instance of that class.

Comment: Hi Greg, Sorry I am not able to follow this... all i need is to get the folder which is reamed and its new path so that I can store it somewhere. In the new class extending `Change` class it is asking to override 5 different methods. How can I get the folder which user has renamed in this `change` class and its new and old path. or If you can point me to some example it would be of great help. Thanks.

Comment: You have the information in your RenameParticipant when you create your Change object - so pass the information to your Change class.